# laravel Image source not readable

Tags: php, image, laravel, readable

hello everyone this my form

```
if (Input::file()) {

    $image = Input::file('dataimage');

    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $path = public_path('resimler/' . $filename);

    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(250, 172.5)->save($path);

    $userprofile->image = $path;
    $userprofile->save();

}
```

but I'm getting an error.

I thank you for your help.
I'm trying to upload pictures.

Comment: Can you add the output of the error to your question?

Comment: https://hizliresim.com/1gVakY